# How do I get my record name instead of RecordID?

Tags: lightning-web-components, object, record, name

Currently, I have three objects namely: User, Review and Cases where a user can create a case and other users can make reviews on the cases. This is illustrated in the schema as shown below:

[image]

In my UI, I created hyperlinks to link the cases and reviewer in the review. However, with my current code I am unable to obtain the Case's name or the User's name. I am only able to obtain their RecordID.

[image]

My current code to get a single review is as shown:

```
import REVIEW_OBJECT from "@salesforce/schema/Review__c";

import REVIEW_ID_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Review__c.Name"
import REVIEW_CASE_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Review__c.Case__c"
import REVIEW_REVIEWED_BY_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Review__c.Reviewed_By__c"

export default class Echo extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId;
    
    @wire(getRecord,{
        recordId: "$recordId",
        fields: [
            REVIEW_ID_FIELD,
            REVIEW_CASE_FIELD,
            REVIEW_REVIEWED_BY_FIELD
        ]
    })
    reviewRecord;

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: REVIEW_OBJECT})
    reviewObjectInfo;

    handleNavigateCase() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.reviewRecord.data.fields['Case__c'].value,
                objectApiName: 'Case__c',
                actionName: 'view'
            }
        });
    }

    get reviewCaseID(){

        let reviewCaseIDInformation = {
            label: '',
            value: ''
        }

        if(this.reviewObjectInfo.data && this.reviewRecord.data){
            reviewCaseIDInformation['label'] = this.reviewObjectInfo.data.fields['Case__c'].label
            //this is returning the case ID not the case name
            reviewCaseIDInformation['value'] = this.reviewRecord.data.fields['Case__c'].value
        }

        return reviewCaseIDInformation;
    }
```

The data fields in my this.reviewRecord.data.fields['Case__c'] only contains the Case recordID and not the case name.
[image]

How do I get the case name '123' instead of its recordID 'a055h00000bYOrnAAG' to display in the hyperlink instead.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try spanning via the relationship name like below

```
import REVIEW_CASE_NAME_FIELD from "@salesforce/schema/Review__c.Case__r. CaseNumber"
```

The syntax is

```
import PARENT_REFERENCED_FIELD_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/object.relationship.field';
```